# SQL Server not showing column specs

Tags: sql-server

Using the command

```
sp_columns 'DimDiagnosis'
```

gives me the column names and column specs for an existing table `dimDiagnosis`.

But when I try the same syntax for a temp table that I am producing,

```
sp_columns '#Diagnosis'
```

gives me only column names; I am not getting column specs. What is the solution?

Comment: Temp tables reside in the tempdb. Have you tried something like `use tempdb; exec sp_columns '#Diagnosis'`?

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thanks.  Apparently you can also use the same syntax for queries on perm databases as well as tempdb.   Ron

Comment: How do I approve this answer?  There is no checkmark to click on..  Ron L.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temp tables reside in the tempdb. You should be able to use either:

```sql
use tempdb; exec sp_columns '#Diagnosis'
```

or:

```sql
exec tempdb..sp_columns '#Diagnosis'
```